# Rounding down NOW() function for use in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

[image]Morning all. A quick question for you to ponder this morning, the answer of which is probably quite easy for some.... but for me I can't fathom it hehe

So i have some data being pulled from api.open-meteo.com, just some weather data split up by the hour, as you can see in the picture. I want to separate the data showing current hour and 8 hours after the current time on a HUD display using the data on the right (which is the HUD in progress). The times on the right need to be dynamic as you'd think, the current hour 8 after.

I was using the floor method to round down the first 'time' to the hour, and then subsequently just adding one hour to every column using the formulas:

```
=FLOOR(NOW(),"1:00")
=N1+(1*(1/24))
=O1+(1*(1/24))
```

The main problem being I can't use the VLOOKUP with the above formulas because for some reason it isn't working, even though if I pop in a formula like `=N1=A10` it comes up as true.

Any ideas as a work around? Would prefer a simple setup with just cell formulas but I don't mind diving into VBA territory if required!

Any ideas floating around?

https://temp-file-share.web.app/d/egJUZfM2tW

Comment: What's the VLOOKUP formula you're using?

Comment: The top row in the blue is : =$AD$3 & VLOOKUP(N1,$A$2:$H$49,2,0)     -     =$AD$3 & VLOOKUP(O1,$A$2:$H$49,2,0)      -     =$AD$3 & VLOOKUP(P1,$A$2:$H$49,2,0) and so on.... so it pulls the temperature icon and then shows the temp

Comment: Excel VBA to generate a markdown table  ...  https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html

Comment: What **exactly**is in N1? Looking to your picture and supposing that you have in N1 the current date at 09 does not match with data in the first column. In the 10th looks to be 08...

Comment: N1 is the formula =FLOOR(NOW(),"1:00") To give me the current date/hour to the current hour only

Comment: OK. Now, what is in the first column? Are you sure that it is formatted as `Date`?

Comment: Updated the original post with a link to the spreadsheet in question :)

Comment: Most of us don't download spreadsheets from here...

Comment: Well then, looks like we're sticking with comments :P ..... erm the first column in the data pull is formatted as custom date yes ..... dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: Did you try SUMIFS to get yor desired output? SUMIFS can be used as a VLOOKUP function if the desired ooutput is numeric and probably will be easier working with hours

Comment: The way Excel keeps the numbers (with decimals) may be tricky. I would suggest you to format both (Data) ranges similarly then copy each of the two ranges then paste as values. `Vlookup` needs to compare **similar formatted** data. Download from [here](https://easyupload.io/7yf3eg) the well formatted workbook (I mean, to allow Vlookup working  well).

Comment: I've not given sumifs a try yet no, i'll have a look into it though for sure... Would they still work with the times in my HUD display being dynamic?

Comment: Do you keep the (Vlookup) formulas as they are and only import Wether data? I am asking that to also create a piece of code able to automatically create the necessary range to be matched, in N1:AB1

Comment: Yes. I've kept the formulas set. The only thing that changes is the first time, which matches the current hour... which updates the other hours as they are just essentially adding 1 hour.... and then the VLOOKUPS work off those times, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next updated code. It will format the necessary range in a way to make formulas bellow the range "N1:AB1" to match the imported data:

```
Sub openWeather()
  Const url As String = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=53.288&longitude=-1.2881&hourly=temperature_2m,precipitation_probability,precipitation,rain,snowfall,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,windgusts_10m,is_day&windspeed_unit=mph&forecast_days=1"
  Dim json As Object, ws As Worksheet, dataSet As Long, currRow As Long
  
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  currRow = 2
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Application.EnableEvents = False
       For dataSet = 1 To json("hourly")("time").Count
        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = Replace(json("hourly")("time")(dataSet), "T", " ")               'timestamp
        ws.Cells(currRow, 2) = json("hourly")("temperature_2m")(dataSet)                        'temp
        ws.Cells(currRow, 3) = json("hourly")("precipitation")(dataSet)                         'rain
        ws.Cells(currRow, 4) = json("hourly")("snowfall")(dataSet)                              'snow
        ws.Cells(currRow, 5) = json("hourly")("precipitation_probability")(dataSet)             'probability
        ws.Cells(currRow, 6) = json("hourly")("windspeed_10m")(dataSet)                         'speed
        ws.Cells(currRow, 7) = json("hourly")("winddirection_10m")(dataSet)                     'direction
        ws.Cells(currRow, 8) = json("hourly")("is_day")(dataSet)                                'day / night
        currRow = currRow + 1
       Next dataSet
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status: " & .Status
    End If
  End With
  
  For Each cel In ws.Range("G2:G" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Cells


  Next cel
  
  processRangeForVlookup ws, False 'it creates the appropriate range in N1:AB1
End Sub

Sub processRangeForVlookup(ws As Worksheet, Optional boolChangeDate As Boolean = False)
 Dim rngD As Range
 'Create the necessary range to be compared:
 ' first cell to contain local time/local hour:
 ws.Range("N1").Formula = Evaluate("=FLOOR(now(), """ & Format(Hour(Now), "00") & ":00"")")
 ws.Range("O1").Formula = "=N1+(1*(1/24))": ws.Range("P1").Formula = "=O1+(1*(1/24))"
 ws.Range("O1:P1").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("O1:AB1")
 Set rngD = ws.Range("N1:AB1")
 With rngD
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
    .Value = .Value
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With
 If boolChangeDate Then 'to change the date at midnight as the following one.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rngD.Columns.Count
    If Hour(rngD.Cells(1, i).Value) = 0 Then
        rngD.Cells(1, i).Value = Int(rngD.Cells(1, i).Value) + 1
    End If
  Next i
 End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: @Mike T You can download the updated workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/p2eepj).

Comment: Code works great for making the VLOOKUPs to work, and indeed they do! I never thought about the whole .value=.value.... genius! One issue however is with using that formula, for some reason 00:00 (to use today as an example) is setting itself to 17/10/2023 00:00 and not 18/10/2023 00:00.   So the hourly flow jumps back to the beginning of the day for just that one hour, if that makes sense.... uploaded a picture just incase i explained it a bit oddly         https://imgur.com/a/lfEFpFB

Comment: Also i had to update the FLOOR formula significance to "1:00" so that the first value changes depending on the current hour

Comment: @Mike T It looks that this is the way Windows interprets first hour of the day. I mean, as the last of the existing day. I think, we can trick it, if you think that doing it would be better. I mean to add one day to the Date when hour is "00", but did you check how the Whether site treats this aspect? If it does as you (and me) consider that it is normal, I think I can investigate the issue and find a solution...

Comment: @Mike T Please, clearly explain which to be the **first date/hour** and I will try finding a solution for the case of passing over midnight...

Comment: @Mike T Adapted the code to (optionally) change the date at midnight. Even if the date should be the same until "00:00:00" and be changed after "00:00:01". You can do that calling `processRangeForVlookup` with the last `Optional` parameter being `True`. Now, it depends on how the Whether site interprets and returns this midnight in terms of `Date`...

Comment: So the first date/hour should be the actual hour in real time, which is why it needs to be dynamic as it will change when a new hour hits. Annnnd the weather data interprets the hour at midnight as being a new day, so 23:00 is the 17th annnnd 00:00 will change to 18th :)

Comment: @Mike T  OK. I will adapt the code to start building the Date ranges from the local time (Day - Hour). Even if I did  not pay attention to this aspect. It was not part of the question, I would say... :)

Comment: @Mike T Adapted.... Please, test it and send some feedback. Adapted the main sub, too. I mean, I did not remove the part able to add a day to the midnight time. Maybe you want to explore it, but I modified the main code to call `processRangeForVlookup` with the optional last parameter  as `False`...

Comment: Yessir, it works perfectly :) I need to do a bit of jiggling around with the cells now to fit them into a new HUD, but you've done wonders :) can't thank you enough for sure :)

Comment: Not clear for me what "fit them into a new HUD" means... If you place a new question and tag me (here or somewhere else), if I will be available I will try helping.